# how can i fix this operator overloading with the same class but different in template argument?

Tags: c++

I am very confused about how to get the template argument of the returned object in simple operator overloading.

This is my code:

```c++
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class numeric {
    public:
        numeric(): value_{0} {}
        numeric(T value): value_{value} {} 
        numeric(const numeric& other) { value_ = other.value_; }

        ~numeric() {}

        template <typename O> 
        numeric<T> operator+(const numeric<O>& other) {
            return numeric<T>(value_ + other.value_); 
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<
        (std::ostream& os, const numeric& other) {
            os << other.value_;
            return os; 
        }
   private:
        T value_;
};

int main() {
     numeric<int> x = 10;
     numeric<float> y = 5.5;
     
     std::cout << (x + y); 

     return 0;
}
```

And my desired result was to print out `15.5` on the console.

Comment: Does this code even compile? Please describe exactly what the issue is with the shown code.

Comment: So what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: Please edit the error message into the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your attempt didn't have a problem with accessing a private member of another class - which could be worked around by making the member public - you would have a problem with inconsistent behaviour where `x + y` results in 15 because the type of the result is `numeric<int>`. `y + x` would yield the desired 15.5.

You can fix both the access problem, and the return type by using friend operator overload template. Use a template type parameter for both operands. Return wrapper of common type. You'll need to define it outside the class template so that you don't get a different definition for each class template instance:

```
template <typename T>
class numeric {
...
    template<class L, class R>
    friend auto operator+(const numeric<L>&, const numeric<R>&);
...
};

template<class L, class R>
auto operator+(const numeric<L>& l, const numeric<R>& r) {
    using common_type = numeric<std::common_type_t<L, R>>;
    return common_type(l.value_ + r.value_); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for saving me. I hope I learned more about the class templates in `<type_traits>` header